# How to implement a loading screen using storyboard?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

In a Corona app using the storyboard library, what are the best practices for adding a loading screen between scenes? I'm guessing it should go somewhere in scene:enterScene() but I'm not sure how to make it work with Corona's rendering process. As I understand it, if I do the following, the loading screen would never be displayed since Corona waits until the code path has finished and then draws everything at once.

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
  showLoadingScreenOverlay()
  loadEverything()
  hideLoadingScreenOverlay()
end
```

Is the correct approach to create a new storyboard scene for the loading screen itself? If so, how can I load the other content in the background while the loading scene is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you should be using loadScene():
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/loadScene.html

This will only call the createScene part of your new scene2...
Then what you could do is update loading progress in the createScene of scene2, and verify every x milliseconds in your original scene1 the loading progress. When it is 100%, just call goToScene in scene1 and it will load scene2 instantly.

Comment: Hey Teddy, to follow up on this, how does one check the loading progress? Does it have something to do with the response from loadScene()? Or do I create some kind of callback inside the destination scene's createScene method?

Comment: You would need to create the loading progress tracking manually.
Let's say that for example in your createScene method you create 4 controls A, B, C, D. At the top of the same scene declare a variable called gLoadingProgress = 0
In createScene, after having loaded each control, add 25 to gLoadingProgress.
So after loading A, gLoadingProgress is equal to 25, after B, 50, after C, 75, after D, 100.
In your original scene you just check the value of gLoadingProgress and act according to that. Makes sense ?
This is a very simple example, quite dirty etc but you will get the idea :)

Comment: Thanks Teddy. I think I'll add an event listener at the runtime level, and dispatch a "sceneDidLoad" event or something once everything has loaded. I'm not too concerned about showing percentages, but it's nice to know that I can do that.